# count of users who've bought same item on a given day 1,2,3,...n in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I using MySql version 5.7

I have a table that looks like this:

```
user_id  item_id      date
   1        2       2020-01-01
   1        2       2020-01-01
   1        2       2020-01-01
   1        3       2020-01-01
   1        4       2020-01-01
   33       7       2020-02-02
   33       7       2020-02-02
   44       11      2020-02-02
   44       11      2020-02-02
```

I want to count number of users who have bought same item on a given day.

Desired result:

```
  date        one   two    three
2020-01-01     1     0       1
2020-02-02     0     2       0
```

one column = number of users who've bought same item once in a given day 
two column = number of users who've bought same item twice in a given day.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No because it 's one user with user_id = 1

Comment: Instead, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Two levels of aggregation:

```
select date,
       sum(cnt = 1) as one,
       sum(cnt = 2) as two,
       sum(cnt = 3) as three
from (select date, user_id, item_id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by uesr_id, item_id
     ) ui
group by date
```